# How to start a program and close it right after it's launched with BAT/CMD file?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

There are two program A and B. What I want to do is:
1,Launch program A;
2,Close program A;
3,Launch program B;
4,Close program B;

How can I write the bat file?

My previous work;

```
A.exe
TSKILL A
B.exe
TSKILL B
```

However,when I launch the program A. It keeps running and the rest of the bat files doesn't run at all.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: When the bat file launches program A, it passes to control to it.

Comment: @fixer1234. So it's infeasible for me to implement such a operation?

Comment: `START /WAIT A.exe` will wait until `A` ends

Comment: Also, `TSKILL` is not a valid command on Windows 7

Comment: I'm just new to BAT file.Thanks for your reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `START /WAIT A.exe` will start `A.exe` and wait for it to terminate before the script continues to execute the next line.

However, if you would like to automatically kill `A.exe` after a set time limit, use this:

```
@ECHO OFF
START /I A.exe
TIMEOUT 10 & REM Waits 10 seconds before executing the next command
TASKKILL /F /IM A.exe
START /I B.exe
TIMEOUT 10 & REM TIMEOUT only works on Windows 7 and later
TASKKILL /F /IM B.exe
PAUSE
```